# Take full advantage of processor speed on Windows machine

Tags: multithreading, performance, perl

New member here but long time Perl programmer.

I have a process that I run on a Windows machine that iterates through combinations of records from arrays/lists to identify a maximum combination, following a set of criteria.

On an old Intel i3 machine, an example would take about 45 mins to run.  I purchased a new AMD Ryzen 7 machine that on benchmarks is about 7 or 8 times faster than the old machine.  But the execution time was only reduced from 45 to 22 minutes.

This new machine has crazy processor capabilities, but it does not appear that Perl takes advantage of these.

Are there Perl settings or ways of coding to take advantage of all of the processor speed that I have on my new machine?  Threads, etc?

thanks

Comment: Was that a single-threaded or a multi-threaded benchmark? Given that this sounds like a CPU-bound, single-threaded problem, using an interpreter that is not friendly to the CPU's branch predictor, a 2× speedup sounds about right. If your problem can be parallelized (and it sounds like this would be comparatively easy) then I bet you can get your program to complete within 2 minutes. Unfortunately, Perl's parallel programming story is not very good, especially on Windows. You can still use the built-in `threads` module, though.

Comment: multi threaded benchmark

Comment: It's a single process that is running to combine records from arrays and get a total value, then compare to the next.  I don't know if multiple threads can be used in the code, but does Perl have a way to optimize execution with all resources available?

Comment: How many arrays are there, and how large are they? And does the computation on each array depend on the results from other arrays? Because this sounds like you could have 16 threads/processes where each thread does the computation on 1/16 of the arrays, and afterwards you aggregate the results from all arrays. On the other hand, if most of the time is spend on loading the arrays (e.g. from a spinning disk, or from a network resource) then having a fancy processor won't speed that up.

Comment: Can you post an actual program that approximates your real task?  (I presume that your real program is too large to post here.) So that we can offer more specific advice.  The "machine speed" (CPU? MB? disks?) doesn't in general directly translate into a speed of execution of a whole program, which normally combines resources.  Also, Perl is not meant to be a speed demon that utilizes all kinds of modern hardware optimizations.  But, if you rewrite your program then you can probably get it far better than 2x on the new machine.

Comment: The arrays are all in memory.  It's an algorithm for creating a fantasy baseball team.  There is criteria about combinations of players and salary limits, but the principal point is to create a maximum combination of player value.  The process executes about 100000 combinations per second on my new machine.  Does Python work better when running in a CMD prompt environment?

Comment: If you can rewrite your program then there can surely be a better speed-up with such a better machine. You'd pay close attention to what parts of the program take most, what  they do and how to tweak them for modern architecture and faster CPU/MB, etc.  Profile and see what you can do with the most expensive parts.  Parallelizing even just those things may give you an extra factor.  Etc. Standard optimization.

Comment: Languages? In general, I'd expect the thing to only be (a little) faster in Perl than in Python, but then that depends entirely on details. It can of course happen that some parts of the code benefit from some C-library in Python, or from a particular language feature.  Dropping to C/C++/Rust/etc (don't forget modern Fortran) - that's at least an order of magnitude right there, specially with long loops and lots of logic.

Comment: By itself Python would probably run slower *but* Python has much better support in the standard library for doing parallel stuff. Python's threads are actually worse than Perl's threading model in this context, but Python's `multiprocessing` library is pretty neat (similar to the `forks` module in Perl). Python's standard library also includes a ProcessPoolExecutor that integrates with its async/await features, roughly similar to Parallel::ForkManager in Perl.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way to use threads.  It's a brute force algorithm that simply combines the quality of baseball players  - one at each position - and invalidates the combination if it is over a salary or too many players from one team.  I think the algorithm is as efficient as possible, but maybe could tweak.  Maybe the key is a compiled language into an exe rather than interpreted language.

Answer (score 1):

Perl by default will only use a single thread and thus only a single CPU core. This means it will only use a small part of what current multi-core systems offer. It has the ability to make use of multiple threads though and thus multiple CPU core. But this needs to be explicitly done, i.e. the implementation needs to be adapted to make use of parallel execution. This can involve major changes to the algorithm used to solve your problem. And not all problems can be easily parallelized.

Apart from the Perl is not the preferred languages if performance is the goal. There is lots of overhead due to being a dynamically typed language and no explicitly control over memory allocation. Languages like C, C++ or Rust which are closer to the hardware start with significantly less overhead and then allow even more low-level control to further reuse overhead. But they don't magically parallelize either.

Comment: Rust gets pretty close to automagic parallelization: given a pipeline `large_array.iter().map(|x| expensive_computation(x))`, just installing Rayon and changing `iter()` to `par_iter()` usually gets the job done. GCC's OpenMP support is also pretty neat. But saying “Rewrite it in Rust” is not helpful, and neither is mentioning C/C++. If you're saying that restructuring the algorithm could take a lot of effort, porting the code to another language is going to take even more effort. Here, I'd expect a 10× speedup for parallelization, 10× for a language with an optimizing compiler, 100× for both.

Comment: Maybe it's worth getting a C compiler.  It's been a long time since I used it, but it runs fast.

Comment: @amon: *"Rust gets pretty close to automagic parallelization:"* - only if the problem can easily be parallelized.  While the OP's short problem description of *"iterates through combinations of records from arrays/lists to identify a maximum combination, following a set of criteria."* might mean that each element could be processed independently from each other as done in you proposal, it does not actually imply it.